# how to set the classpath using a java program without setting it form command line?

Tags: java

How to set the `classpath` using a java program without setting it form command line?

Comment: 6 ways to set the classpath: http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-ways-of-setting-java-classpath.html

Comment: @MYYN - it's four to me, the first two are equivalent and the 'current directory' thing is too trivial and limited ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three common ways to set the classpath:

- define the environment variable `CLASSPATH`
- add `-cp` argument to the java call
- declare the classpath in a jar manifest file.

I recommend the second option. Just write a shell script or batch file that executes java with the classpath and the class containing the main method.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest ways to set classpath

- from the command line
- from the environment ($CLASSPATH)
- if your program is packed in a .jar, from the Class-Path: field in the MANIFEST.MF